# How to use WhenEvent with a vector ODE in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, vector, event-detection

I have an ODE system I'd like to specify as a vector equation in `NDSolve`.  I'm not clear on how to use `WhenEvent` for a system specified in this way.  Ultimately I'd like `WhenEvent` to change the value of one of the state variables in the vector equation when it reaches a threshold.

For example, the following code doesn't work because `WhenEvent[y[t]==0, ...]` is applying a conditional test to a list of values. Replacing this with `y[t][[1]]==0` also doesn't work.

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == {{.1, -.2}, {-.1, .2}}.y[t], y[0] == {1, 1}, 
 WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y[t] -> 1]}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 7):

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[t] == {{.1, -.2}, {-.1, .2}}.y[t], y[0] == {1, 1},
            WhenEvent[Norm[y[t] - {0.9460552574072016`, 1.053944742592798`}] <= .01, y[t] -> {1, 1}]}
           , y[t], {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[y[t] /. s[[1]] /. t -> u, {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Although this works, the Norm[] is an attribute of the whole system of state variables.  This did give me the idea to try Part[y[t],1]<=0.1, which seems to work.  Not sure why Part[] works when y[t][[1]] doesn't...

Comment: @dvasseur `y[t][[1]]` works OK. Your error was using `==` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 6):

The proper way to generate events is to symbolically refer to vector elements, that is: using `Indexed` (since v10). Here I assume that the vector length `n` can change (in that case one must adjust the matrix used in `y'[t]` also), and I also use a programmatic way to set up events for all vector elements (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120379/89)).

```
ClearAll[y, t];

n = 2; (* vector length *)
x = 0; (* event threshold *)
events = WhenEvent[Indexed[y[t], #] == x,
                   y[t] -> ReplacePart[y[t], # -> 1]] & /@ Range@n;
sol = NDSolve[{
        y'[t] == {{.1, -.2}, {-.1, .2}}.y[t],
        y[0] == Table[1, {n}],
        events}, y, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `Part` instead of `Indexed`, premature evaluation of symbolic expressions (here `Part[y[t], #] == x`) during `NDSolve` fails. One must either use `Indexed` or hardcode the threshold value `x` into the `WhenEvent`.

```
ClearAll[y, t];

n = 2;
x = 0;
events = WhenEvent[Part[y[t], #] == x, 
     y[t] -> ReplacePart[y[t], # -> 1]] & /@ Range@n;
sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == {{.1, -.2}, {-.1, .2}}.y[t], 
    y[0] == Table[1, {n}], events}, y, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution, just change the `WhenEvent` part to `WhenEvent[First@y[t] == 0, y[t] -> {1, Last@y[t]}]`

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == {{.1, -.2}, {-.1, .2}}.y[t], y[0] == {1, 1}, 
  WhenEvent[First@y[t] == 0, y[t] -> {1, Last@y[t]}]}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

*Mathematica* gives

> [image]

Comment: +1. I always feel a sense of relief when the result confirms that `First@y[t]` is evaluated the way you hoped it would be. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. I like something straightforward, and Mathematica rarely let me down:)

Comment: @MichaelE2 For the record, `Part` (`First`, `Last`, etc.) does *not* always work as one would expect, especially when it comes to symbolic evaluation, see my answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for telling me this. However, I think in the case of fixed dimension, `HoldAll` attribute of `WhenEvent` is exactly the key to success. With this attribute, MMTC would first get the solution of explicit dimension, then `Part` or `First` without any problem. I admit this cannot handle the arbitrary dimension and it prevent us from encapsulating the whole events before the show up of `NDSolve`.